# Using solaar with MX Master 3S, all options are locked

Tags: mouse-scroll, solaar

My mouse isn't paired to anything else, to my knowledge, but all options are looked, per screenshot below;

I installed solar via Ubuntu's software manager.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me too!
All paired up and working properly but everything locked as in op picture.
Doh! Click on the lock and it unlocks.

Comment: Despite the given downvote, this was actually the answer. It never occurred to me that the lock could be pressed, and I would have never found it without this - so thanks.